# From Node.js how to call REST API that uses ASP.NET web API windows authentication?

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, node-rest-client

I am using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm package to call api that uses windows authentication.
I make call to GET method as below. But I get **401** UNAUTHORIZED as response code.

```
var request = require('request');
 
var options = {
  url: 'http://url',
  method : 'GET',
  json : true,
  headers: {        
        'Authorization': 'NTLM MpJfHMQjKT4V8txCgAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJAFIASABUAFQAUAAvAGgAcQBtAGUAcgBjAGgAcwB2AGMAMAAxAHQAMQBiAC4AZABzAHQAZQBzAHQALgBkAHIAdQBnAHMAdABvAHIAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEZDtgUbISIZWdfhvrcI7aujEgQQAQAAAJTRhB/tA+DyAAAAAA=='
    }
};
 
function callback(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
  }
}
 
request(options, callback);
```

Please help me, how to call API that uses ASP.NET web API windows authentication using node.js ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anyway to call rest api with windows authentication?